# Ungrouped Long List Selector

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

Okay, So I am trying to bind a list of objects with a **DisplayName** property to a long list selector.

**XAML Code**

```
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="lls_TemplateFields" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="450" Grid.Row="2" Height="400" LayoutMode="List" Background="#FF9E9D9D" IsGroupingEnabled="False">
            <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="24"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
 </phone:LongListSelector>
```

**C# Code**

```
List<AttributeDefinition> m_SelectedAttributes = new List<AttributeDefinition>();
lls_TemplateFields.ItemsSource = m_SelectedAttributes;
```

My Class **AttributeDefinition** contains a property for **DisplayName**. If I group the the list using a group key then the list will show up, however I cannot get just a plain list of items to show up. Like a **listbox** in WPF C#.

I am using this list to represent a list of chosen AttributeDefinitions from another list that shows all the AttributeDefinitions grouped alphabetically by their DisplayName property, and the Display Value is Binded to the DisplayName Property like shown below...

**XAML**

```
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="lls_AttributeList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="450" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="450" HideEmptyGroups="True" IsGroupingEnabled="True" SelectionChanged="SelectionChanged">
         <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                      <Grid>
                            <Border BorderThickness="2">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}" FontSize="24"/>
                            </Border>
                      </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <phone:LongListSelector.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                      <Grid Width="50" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Blue">
                            <Border BorderThickness="4">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Foreground="White" FontSize="38" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </Border>
                      </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector.GroupHeaderTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

**C#**

```
List<AttributeKeyGroup<AttributeDefinition>> DataSource = AttributeKeyGroup<AttributeDefinition>.CreateGroups(AttributeData,
                                                                                                        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture,
                                                                                                        (AttributeDefinition aDef) => { return aDef.Type; },
                                                                                                        true);

lls_AttributeList.ItemsSource = DataSource;
```

This list works just fine. And the data in the background is functioning properly, because as I select items from the total list of **attributedefinitions** they are removed from the **LongListSelector** and added to the **LongListSelector** of the selected lists **Itemssource**

**For further inquiry into more code surrounding this User Control please feel free to ask I will disclose as much code as I can without breaking my non-disclosure agreement with my work. Thank you for taking the time to read and possibly help. Much appreciated.**

Answer (score 0):

```
List<AttributeDefinition> m_SelectedAttributes = new List<AttributeDefinition>();
lls_TemplateFields.ItemsSource = m_SelectedAttributes;
```

because you just instantiated this list and binding it right away? How about adding some items into the list

Comment: Wrong. It is because it is not an Observable Collection. If you had read the entire page, you would realize that at first there would be no selected attributes. I merely put that first line of code to show that the object was being instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

There are two answers to this. I have tried both and both work.

[1] You have to set the `LongListSelector.ScrollTo(object)` to the first object of your list when you update the data if the list has 1 or more items. Such as...

```
lls_TemplateFields.ItemsSource = m_SelectedAttributes;

if(m_SelectedAttributes.Count > 0)
{
     lls_TemplateFields.ScrollTo(m_SelectedAttributes[0]);
}
```

[2] The proper way to fix this is to use ObservableCollections which work better with DataBinding and the WP8 WPF SDK UI to update on adding objects to the `ObservableCollection`.

```
ObservableCollection<AttributeDefinition> m_SelectedAttributes =
               new  ObservableCollection<AttributeDefinition>();


lls_TemplateFields.ItemsSource = m_SelectedAttributes
```